# How to compare multiple columns in MySql and display result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table. I want to compare two tables gift and show the result. But I don't want to show N/A value. and I want to show result matching value and not matching value. if table1 gift is match the table2 gift and table1 user_it is match the table2 user_id then show status yes. otherwise status show no and also count the gift quantity.

**Table1**

| id | user id | name | gift1 | gift2 | gift3 | gift4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 511 | Md. Amir Hossain | N/A | Pad | Mobile | Laptop |
| 2 | 522 | Md. Faruk Khan | Mobile | Book | Pen | N/A |
| 3 | 533 | Md. Rifat | Book | N/A | Laptop | Watch |
| 4 | 544 | Md. Hossain Ali | Laptop | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| 6 | 559 | Md. Milon khan | Watch | Pen | N/A | N/A |
| 7 | 559 | Md. Rifat | Mobile | Pen | Watch | Book |
| 8 | 522 | Md. Faruk Khan | Pen | N/A | N/A | Mobile |

**Table2**

| id | user id | name | gift name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 511 | Md. Amir Hossain | Watch |
| 3 | 533 | Md. Rifat | Watch |
| 9 | 544 | Md. Hossain Ali | Laptop |
| 10 | 522 | Md. Faruk Khan | Pen |

I want to show like this:

**Result**

| name | gift | qty | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Md. Amir Hossain | Pad | 1 | No |
| Md. Amir Hossain | Mobile | 1 | No |
| Md. Amir Hossain | Laptop | 1 | No |
| Md. Faruk Khan | Mobile | 2 | No |
| Md. Faruk Khan | Book | 1 | No |
| Md. Faruk Khan | Pen | 2 | Yes |
| Md. Rifat | Book | 2 | No |
| Md. Rifat | Laptop | 1 | No |
| Md. Rifat | Watch | 2 | Yes |
| Md. Rifat | Pen | 1 | No |
| Md. Hossain Ali | Laptop | 1 | Yes |
| Md. Faruk Khan | Pen | 1 | Yes |
| Md. Faruk Khan | Mobile | 1 | No |

Comment: you can add the table creation code with the inserts

Comment: Wrong data model. There must be 3 tables - one for the users, one for all the possible gifts and one for the actual gift receival (who received what gift and when).

Comment: I am inserting and adding the table data in this page: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/109

Comment: it can't be done until you at least add the missing table because I am not a fortune teller. @user25183

Comment: There are issues in your data: different user_ids are associated to different user names in your first table. There are either errors or there's something we don't know yet about your problem.